# looking for reducing time of a big sql request in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:
D with field d1 and field d2
and T with field s
the two fields are of type Varchar2(255)

```
select d2 
FROM 
D , 
(select s from T where (s = 'val_1') OR (s='val_2') OR .. OR (s='val_n')  ) S
WHERE d1 LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%,',S.s),'%')
```

My problem is that the number n is huge (superior than 2500)

then the time to resolve the request is about five minutes

is there a solution to reduce this time

Comment: Show us the execution plan and the definition (`CREATE TABLE`) of both tables including any index defined. You might also want to read this: http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Comment: `CREATE TABLE D (
  d1 varchar2(255) primary key,
  d2 varchar2(255)
)

CREATE TABLE T (
   s varchar2(255) primary key
)
`

there aren't indexes on tables

Comment: Please don't post code comments. Edit your question. And you still haven't shown us the execution plan.

Comment: might need to re-read http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html. Good luck.

Comment: How many values in `T`?  Presumably more than 2500.  But how many more?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with `D`.  This WHERE clause ...

```
WHERE d1 LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%,',S.s),'%')
```

... is deadly.  It means the query needs to probe *every single value* of `D1`.  No regular index will help find a value with a wildcard at each end.

Now let's consider `T`.  This WHERE clause ...

```
 (s = 'val_1') OR (s='val_2') OR .. OR (s='val_n')
```

... apparently has more than 2500 elements in it.  Pure poison to tune.

Despite the assertion (in a comment) that "there aren't indexes on tables" the posted creation table statements have primary keys, so there are indexes available.

But as `T` appears to have just the one column, an index on column `T.S` doesn't make any difference: a Full Fast Index Scan will be as quick (or as slow) as a Full Table Scan.  Given that S is a varchar2(255) that will be pretty slow, as there won't be many values to the block.

For the reasons already stated, the index on `D.D1` is irrelevant, so again we're left with a Full Table Scan as the only access path.

So what's the best execution plan we could hope for?   Something like:

1. Full Table Scan of T
2. Filter of the 2500+ values of S
3. Full Table Scan of D
4. A hash join of T.S and D.D1

...except that those wildcards will mean a Nested Loop operation instead of a Hash Join.

Finally let's consider this statement:

> "the time to resolve the request is about five minutes"

The single post important thing in tuning is have a reasonable expectation of elapsed time.  Five minutes might represent a horribly slow response or a fantastically fast response under the circumstances.  Who can tell?  We certainly cant.  Only the OP can, because only they have the access to the data and hence the ability to answer these questions:

- What is the average length of  columns `D1` and `D2`?
- How many rows are there in table `D`?
- What would be a reasonable to read them all?
- What is the average length of  columns `S`?
- How many rows are there in table `T`?
- What would be a reasonable to read them all?
- How many rows in `T` where `S` matches '%val_1%' through '%val_n%' ?
- How many rows i  `D` where `D1` matches  '%val_1%' through '%val_n%'?
- What would be a reasonable time to match them all?
- What would be a reasonable time to display all the relevant values of D2?

Answer (score 0):

There are indexes as each primary key creates an index. However, using LIKE with a "%" at the beginning of the match string renders the indexes useless.

But in general, having >2500 OR clauses hints at a more fundamental problem. This huge number of OR clauses must have been generated, because no human would ever enter or code such a  query. It seems to me, that part of the query migrated to the code generating the query.

So you should take a step back and ask yourself the question, what rows you really want, what condition the rows need to satisfy. Should the val_1 .. val_n come from outside the database consider putting them into the database first.